# Where to keep DB connection states when running recursive functions with graph searches?

Tags: python, graph, search

Suppose we're traversing a tree stored in a relational database's table.

So we write an algorithm that starts from a given top node and then does breadth-first search on its children.

```
def search(node_id):
    global db
    cursor = db.cursor()
    select all rows from table where parent_id=node_id
    for each row in result
        search(row_id)
```

Actually, when implementing it, we need a cursor object, which comes from a connection object.

What are the trade-offs between working with a global connection object and getting cursors out of it vs. passing the connection object as an argument to the functions?

```
def search(db, node_id):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    select all rows from table where parent_id=node_id
    for each row in result
        search(db, row_id)
```

Comment: I think this is more suitable for StackOverflow. It's a general programming question.

Comment: What trade-offs are you talking about? Since *opinion-based* questions are supposed to be off-topic to SO, I think you should make the question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose best option would be to keep the cursor as the object field.
Something like this:

```
class Sercher:
    def __init__(connection):
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()
        ...

    def search(self, node_id):
        ...
        # access:  self.cursor
        ...
        #recursion
        self.search(next_node_id)
```